# Adding options to Chrome extension button menu?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've searched but I'm not using the right terms or they bring up too many examples for *context-menu* options. I want to know how to add options to the menu that comes up when you **right-click an EXTENSION BUTTON** as seen below with "Block this ad". Anyone know?

[image]